# Logistic regression that allows a probability as gold standard

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Is there any python implementation of the logistic regression, which allows a probability as target (i.e., gold standard).

My data is as follow (The first to three columns: features, the fourth column: gold standard):

```
32 453 65 0.55
15 34 222 0.88
33 66 161 0.76
```

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and [graphlab](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.logistic_classifier.LogisticClassifier.html) seem to allow only 0 or 1 as target.

Comment: The best action to take here is to go back and get number of responses for each probability you calculate. Without it, regression doesn't know how accurate each group is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if you have an intuition of how the probabilities in your last column are estimated, you could try using [weighted logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90649).  In scikit-learn, you would calculate the sample weights as detailed in that stats answer and pass it to the [`LogisticRegression.fit` method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) in its `sample_weight` parameter.

Without any further information about what the probabilities represent, you might transform your data set to look something like this:

```
32 453 65 0, sample_weight = 45
32 453 65 1, sample_weight = 55
15 34 222 0, sample_weight = 12
15 34 222 1, sample_weight = 88
33 66 161 0, sample_weight = 24
33 66 161 1, sample_weight = 76
```

Comment: Why 45 is the weight? In the question, there is no mention about number of responses in each binomial group. Your approach wouldn't work.

Comment: `45 * 0 + 55 * 1` is just a naive interpretation of the fraction 0.55; it seems the simplest thing to try if you don't know all the details of how the 55% has been estimated.  It represents the strong assumption that all the groups can be equally weighted.